# Draw lines on top of image (InDesign)

Tags: adobe-indesign

So noob question coming. I need to draw some connecting lines on top of images but I've been struggling to do so. Everytime I draw a line (with the Pen tool) it just sits on top of the image and erases it. Can you give me a hand here? Thanks in advance!

[image: lines erasing images indesign]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the pen tool you're making a shape using points, just like in Illustrator. Currently, in the top bar you can see that your shape is set to a white fill colour and grey stroke. This is why when you start to make a shape, you are seeing the white triangle on top of your image.

The solution, make a path with just a stroke colour OR use the [line tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/drawing-line-or-shape-tools.html) :)

Hope this helps!