# How to draw parallel curved lines in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, pen-tool, bezier-curve

I am completely new to Illustrator, I've watched some tutorials on it, and decided to create some pretty basic shapes and logo.
I was trying to create a usb logo, but the curved part is quite a difficult one for me.
Please refer to the image : [image]

The circled part is annoying to me. I tried pen tool but it simply doesnt create a curved line but a curved region something like this :[image]

What do I do to make it look correct, can somebody guide me step by step ?

Comment: I looks like you have a fill that needs to be turned off.

Answer (score 0):

1. draw a line with the pen tool
2. increase the line thickness

That's the easiest way to do that, but there are several other methods. You should  look at vector images under a different perspective, the so called "thinking outside of the box". Study Illustrator a bit more, check all the tools and learn how do they work, and you'll be able to create much more and with much less effort.

Not everything is created using blocks of shapes; learn how to manipulate the tools to create your objects more efficiently.

Comment: line tool gives the same kind of result like in the image I showed. I am not able to figure out how to do this

Comment: Sorry, I just fixed my answer, I wanted to say Pen tool

Comment: Regardless, learn how to use the basic tools. There are plenty tutorials on the net about it; you can start at [Adobe help itself](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/drawing-pen-pencil-or-flare.html). GD.SE is not a tutorial website, we try to focus on  questions related to design problems instead.

Comment: Well, I suppose this is a problem!

Comment: Not a "how to solve this design issue" but a "how to do X using X software" type of problem. Check here for what's on-topic on GD.SE http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Conceptually a duplicate of http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/77671/30216